# Please help to adapt this sample code

Tags: ios, core-foundation, cfmutabledictionary

I would like to adapt the sample code below to store a **uint** value rather than a **CGPoint** value in myValues dictionary. I'm not really familiar how to work with CoreFoundation types, so need help here :S

```
    - (void)cacheBeginPointForTouches:(NSSet *)touches
    {

         CFMutableDictionaryRef myValues = CFDictionaryCreateMutable (
                                                      kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                      20,
                                                      NULL,
                                                      NULL
                                                      );



        if ([touches count] > 0) {
            for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
                CGPoint *point = (CGPoint *)CFDictionaryGetValue(myValues, touch);
                if (point == NULL) {
                    point = (CGPoint *)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));
                    CFDictionarySetValue(myValues, touch, point);
                }
                *point = [touch locationInView:view.superview];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exchange all `CGPoint` occurrences to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Ha! Genius. It's the asterisks, I'm not always comfortable around them :) Thanks

Comment: @anna: Asterisks refer to pointers. This may help: http://boredzo.org/pointers Though for this purpose, I recommend using NSValue objects instead of `malloc`ked buffers. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/